How to subscribe xml message using rabbitmq and send that as Response object by converting
Hi I am working on RabbitMQ where i need to subscribe a xml message and convert it to java object and send it back as Response object. Response xml which i need to subscribe** ``
**<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XYZ>
<PROCDATE>06/04/24</PROCDATE>
<PROCTIME>07:55:17.0</PROCTIME>
<REQID>LTEACT-14017147423-000</REQID>
</XYZ>**

`I need help in creating a Subscriber listener which will receive the above xml message and convert it to java object and send it back as Response .XYZ POJO already created with annotation @xmlRootElement and all. Just help me creating listener class

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
